# How to Re-Size Label to fit any screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

Ok, here's what I'm trying to do: 
I would like to create a scroll view to scroll vertically, in case my text is longer than the screen size (think iPhone 4 vs. iPhone 6).

I've added a scroll view and placed a view within that. I embedded by label for the text within the view.

However, the scroll view currently will scroll only horizontally.

Is there a way to constrain the label width to be the width of the screen? How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can constrain the width to `contentview` to be equal to `scrollview` width. And pin the four sides of `label` to the content view.
Also you will need to pin all sides of content view to scrollview, if you haven't already did that.

Comment: Ok, here's what I did.

Comment: I pinned the scroll view to 25 on both sides, unchecking constrain to margins. Then I pinned the content view to 0 on all four sides, which is within scroll view. After that, I pined the four sides of label to 0. However, the label is just one line and you scroll horizontally to see all of it.

Comment: You should also add a equal width constraint on the content view & scroll view. It will disable horizontal scroll.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you push the constraint button on the bottom of your storyboard pin it to both the left and right side. Uncheck constraint to margins and pin it both 0. :)

Comment: Why do you have to uncheck constraint to margins? What does that do?

Comment: I constrained it to 25 on both sides, but now the label is one line and you scroll to read all of it (see below)

Comment: Storyboard has automatic margins. 20 of the sides of the screen. If you uncheck it you had to constraint them -20 if you wanted it to the sides of the screen. 0 is a more useful number. Did you check the number of lines in your attributes inspector?

Comment: It's set to 10 lines

Comment: If you post your project on to github i can take a look at it

Comment: srvv suggested I add an equal width constraint, which fixed the issue. Thanks for explaining constraint to margin!